# ArrayIndesOutOfBoundsException in custom binary search?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, binary-search

I am trying to implement binary search in Java:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Search 
{
public static void sequential_search(int[] array,int search_variable)
{
    boolean flag = false;
    for(int loop=0;loop<array.length;loop++)
    {
        if(array[loop] == search_variable)
        {
            flag = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(flag == true)
        System.out.println("The value is present");
    else
        System.out.println("The value is absent");
}

public static int binary_search_recursive(int[] array,int low,int high,int search_variable)
{
    if(low > high)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        int mid;
        mid = (low+high)/2;
        if(array[mid] == search_variable)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else if (array[mid] > search_variable)
        {
            return binary_search_recursive(array, low, mid - 1, search_variable);
        }
        else 
        {
            return binary_search_recursive(array, mid + 1, high, search_variable);
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int[] array = {10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1};
    int search_variable;

    System.out.println("Please enter the number to be search:");
    Scanner number = new Scanner(System.in);
    search_variable = number.nextInt();
    System.out.println("The number to be searched is "+search_variable);

    //sequential_search(array,search_variable);

    if ((binary_search_recursive(array, 0, array.length, search_variable)) == 0)
        System.out.println("The value is present");
    else
        System.out.println("The value is absent");

}
```

}

I'm just getting confused while I'm getting out of ArrayOutOfBoundsException, when I enter a term which is not found by the algorithm.

```
Please enter the number to be search:
12
The number to be searched is 12
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
    at Search.binary_search_recursive(Search.java:32)
    at Search.binary_search_recursive(Search.java:42)
    at Search.binary_search_recursive(Search.java:42)
    at Search.binary_search_recursive(Search.java:42)
    at Search.main(Search.java:59)
```

Any input on this would be helpful.
Thanks :)

Comment: Please add line numbers. What is on lines 32 and 42 ?

Comment: Did you try to debug this using a debugger?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the issue here is that your `low` and `high` variables represent the range [low, high), with the `high` value excluded.  This means that your base case, which is currently

```
if(low > high)
{
    return 0;
}
```

should probably be

```
if(low >= high)
{
    return 0;
}
```

Since if you have the range [low, low), there aren't any elements left.  Requiring `low > high` before you terminate means that you will need low to actually exceed `high`, which shouldn't be possible.

If I'm correct about this, this also means that one of your recursive calls to the function has the wrong upper bound.  Specifically, this code:

```
    else if (array[mid] > search_variable)
    {
        return binary_search_recursive(array, low, mid - 1, search_variable);
    }
```

should be

```
    else if (array[mid] > search_variable)
    {
        return binary_search_recursive(array, low, mid, search_variable);
    }
```

since if `high` is exclusive, passing in `mid` as the upper bound is the proper way to get everything up to but not including the middle value.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((binary_search_recursive(array, 0, array.length, search_variable)) == 0)
```

You eventually are checking array[array.length] if you use those arguments. 10 elements means array.length is 10, but the 10th index is of course undefined.

```
if ((binary_search_recursive(array, 0, array.length-1, search_variable)) == 0)
```